# Weird behaviour for colon operator with arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, operator-keyword

I am looking into the code for an Octave function I found, and I found out a weird use of the colon operator. I could not find this behaviour explained in documentation or official MathWorks blogs (e.g. [Colon Operator](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/10/all-about-the-colon-operator/))

Suppose we have a couple of vectors:

```
>> a=[1,2,3]
a =
   1   2   3
>> b=[7,8,9]
b =
   7   8   9
```

Now if you use the colon operator you have:

```
>> a:b
ans =
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

What I understood after several tries is that the above use is equivalent to:

```
>> a(1):b(1)
ans =
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Is my assumption correct? 
Is there some documentation somewhere?

Comment: In MATLAB, the same behavior can be reproduced.

Comment: you'll find the implemenation in https://hg.octave.org/octave/file/tip/libinterp/octave-value/ov.cc#l2592 , taking only the first element of base, increment and limit

Comment: Note on the duplicate: it is indeed the same underlying cause. However, the duplicate does not ask for (and thus its answers do not mention) Octave syntax. This happens to be the exact same (see my answer here), as Octave is intended to be a MATLAB clone.

Comment: @Adriaan GNU Octave wasn't intended to be a MATLAB clone. Users and contributors saw parallels and provided patches to enable them to run MATLAB code in Octave. Today the goal is to not break compatibility with MATLAB but Octave still has unique elements not available in MATLAB

Comment: @Andy “users and contributors saw parallels” — those were not a coincidence. And it’s not just a few parallels, Octave was an implementation of the MATLAB language as it existed at the time, with a bunch of additions that the author thought were improvements.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You can discuss this with John W. Eaton if you ever meet him. He told us multiple times that this wasn't his initial intend when he started developing GNU Octave.

Comment: @Andy Yeah, I’m sure the syntax being identical, and all the function names and argument names being identical, is just a big old coincidence. Eaton might not have cared about making things compatible, but he did set out to write an interpreter based on the MATLAB syntax. That makes it a clone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually documented in the official [MATLAB documentation on colon](https://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/colon.html?s_tid=doc_ta#bt1v7kq-j):

> **`j` — Beginning operand**
> *real scalar*
> Beginning operand, specified as a real scalar integer-valued `fi` object or built-in numeric type.
>
> If you specify non-scalar arrays, MATLAB interprets `j:i:k` as `j(1):i(1):k(1)`.

So yes, it indeed does what you mention it does for array syntax, take the first element of the vector.

Octave follows this implementation, see [the official source code](https://hg.octave.org/octave/file/tip/libinterp/octave-value/ov.cc#l3354) (thanks to [Andy for finding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250152/weird-behaviour-in-octave-colon-operator#comment101001078_57250152))